# Powershell invoke-expression doesn't work with filter switch

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a program that lets users to do different kinds of queries on Active Directory. I want to make it in a way that lets them to chose which attributes they want to show in the output, and also filter the output in several ways.
As I don't know during writing the code how many attributes they will chose, it seemd the easiest way to produce a string out of the attributelist, and invoke the string with invoke-expression. This way works perfectly with attributes, but not at all with filters.

I've found several kinds of filter syntaxes but neither works when I put them in a string and try to invoke that with "Invoke-expression"

This:

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(19))
Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -gt $time} -SearchBase 'CN=Users,DC=home,DC=local' -Properties samAccountname, LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{n='Felhasználónév'; e='samAccountName'}, @{n='Utolsó bejelentkezés'; e='LastLogonDate'} | Out-String
```

Gives me the result I want.
While this:

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(19))
$out = "Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -gt $time} -SearchBase 'CN=Users,DC=home,DC=local' -Properties samAccountname, LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{n='Felhasználónév'; e='samAccountName'}, @{n='Utolsó bejelentkezés'; e='LastLogonDate'} | Out-String"

Write-Host $out
Invoke-Expression $out
```

Gives me the following result:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -gt 05/05/2019 19:05:46} -SearchBase 'OU=Testing,DC=home,DC=local' -Properties samAccountname, LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{n='Username'; e='samAccountName'}, @{n='Last Logon'; e='LastLogonDat
e'}
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'LastLogonTimeStamp -gt 05/05/2019 19:05:46' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: ' at 
position: '26'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -gt 05/05/2019 19:05:46} -Sear ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft 
   .ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Why does every other command works perfectly when invoking them from a string, but not this one? Is there any other way to filter the result? At first I wanna stick to filtering before the query, and not with the where clause, but I'm gonna try that too, if filtering won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels stupid to answer my own question, but I think I found the answer.
Placing escape character before the variable did the trick.

```
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-(19))
$out = "Get-ADUser -Filter {lastlogontimestamp -gt `$time} -SearchBase 'CN=Users,DC=home,DC=local' -Properties samAccountname, LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{n='Felhasználónév'; e='samAccountName'}, @{n='Utolsó bejelentkezés'; e='LastLogonDate'} | Out-String"

Write-Host $out
$expr = Invoke-Expression $out
$expr
```

Returns

```
Felhasználónév Utolsó bejelentkezés  
-------------- --------------------  
Administrator  2019. 05. 24. 18:18:28
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, but mine was **specific to `$true $false` parameters** that are `$true` if present, `$false` if absent for `[switch]` type `[params]`.  I had never needed to override the default params, because those were originally intended for single-use/manual invocation from the command line.

Invoke-Expression simplified calling .ps1 files as subroutines, but this would work directly from the command line console

> `\temp\00405-LoadW.ps1 -skipinit -showbanner:$false | Out-File -filepath 'c:\temp\today\00405-LoadW.log'`

while this would not work when called inside a .ps1 file:

> `Invoke-Expression "\temp\00405-LoadW.ps1 -skipinit -showbanner:$false | Out-File -filepath 'c:\temp\today\00405-LoadW.log'"`

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56298565/5839677) (directly above) has the solution, the **back-tick**

> `

This works both on the command console and from inside a .ps1:

> `` Invoke-Expression "\temp\00405-LoadW.ps1 -skipinit -showbanner:`$false | Out-File -filepath 'c:\temp\today\00405-LoadW.log'" ``

*PS: More time spent on figuring out how to escape the back-tick here than the actual answer.*